# Qualtrics Javascript questions - Matrix Tables

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm having some issues in Qualtrics with certain functions that are easy enough in a single question, but become impossible when using a Matrix Table or a Side-by-Side.

1) Content validation for individual fields in the Matrix Table - currency in the Matrix table, you can only check validation for multiple fields and generate a single error.

2) Required Response for a field based on an entry in the previous field in that row of the Matrix Table

3) Recode Values of text entries in a Matrix Table - there doesn't seem to be a way to this in a Matrix Table. Again, it's very simple to do with a single question.

Basically, I'd like a user to be able to complete only a single row of the Matrix Table if they want, but for the rows they complete, I need to validate specific fields and require response for specific fields, and possibly re-code their text entries.

Is there an easy way to do this with Javascript instead?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that JavaScript will take care of it. I've had to write several scripts because the validation features in Qualtrics are limited, to say the least.

Depending on how your Qualtrics validations options are set up you'll probably have to use functions from Qualtrics' JavaScript. Below is the basic structure you would use. Not really knowing anything about your Qualtrics question ids, I used placeholders.

---

**Update:** I would recommend using the side-by-side question type. 
Here's a
[link to the question/survey](https://ucsf.us.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_3KICVx0i5r5Y4E5&Preview=Survey&BrandID=ucsf)

To get you started off, here is the code for the first student. You need to copy the same pattern for students 2-5. You can go so many ways with validation style (in-line messages, pop-ups) that I didn't even go there. The email validation you can choose in Qualtrics under content validation for the two email columns. You can also choose phone number validation as well. The validation here will just prevent a user from going to the next page until they meet all the criteria. You could explain the validation criteria in the body of the question.

The questions ids I used are listed first and correspond exactly to the placement of the items in the screen shot except for the Y/N question which is different for a side-by-side question and has the id QR~QID9#5~1~1 for yes and QR~QID9#5~1~2 for no. I don't know what your skills are regarding Firebug but you will need to find the ids that pertain to your specific questions and replace the ones below with them.

I would also recommend using Embedded Data variables to feed in the answers so that you have nice clean legible data in your download. From what I remember, the structure of Qualtrics matrix and side-by-side data are not very usable.

Hopefully, this makes sense to you. If not, ask. I know from personal experience how frustrating it is to find javascript support for Qualtrics.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
/*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

//QR~QID9#1~1~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#2~1~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#3~1~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#4~1~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#5~1~1/QR~QID9#5~1~2 - QR~QID9#6~1~1~TEXT
//QR~QID9#1~2~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#2~2~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#3~2~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#4~2~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#5~2~1/QR~QID9#5~2~2 - QR~QID9#6~2~1~TEXT
//QR~QID9#1~3~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#2~3~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#3~3~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#4~3~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#5~3~1/QR~QID9#5~3~2 - QR~QID9#6~3~1~TEXT
//QR~QID9#1~4~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#2~4~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#3~4~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#4~4~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#5~4~1/QR~QID9#5~4~2 - QR~QID9#6~4~1~TEXT
//QR~QID9#1~5~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#2~5~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#3~5~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#4~5~1~TEXT - QR~QID9#5~5~1/QR~QID9#5~5~2 - QR~QID9#6~5~1~TEXT

var notvalidphbook1 = 0, notvalidphbook2 = 0, notvalidphbook3 = 0, notvalidphbook4 = 0, notvalidphbook5 = 0;
var phsbooks; //gets sum of notvalidphbook items

var bookrecode1, bookrecode2, bookrecode3, bookrecode4, bookrecode5;

var notvalidemail1 = 0, notvalidemail2 = 0, notvalidemail3 = 0, notvalidemail4 = 0, notvalidemail5 = 0;
var emails; //gets sum of notvalidemail items

var validates; //validation variable that decides if user proceeds or not

Qualtrics.SurveyPage.Question.prototype.validate = function (element) {

    //Student name entered
    var student1y = $('QR~QID9#1~1~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student2y = $('QR~QID9#1~2~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student3y = $('QR~QID9#1~3~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student4y = $('QR~QID9#1~4~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student5y = $('QR~QID9#1~5~1~TEXT').getValue();

    //Student phone number
    var student1phone = $('QR~QID9#2~1~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student2phone = $('QR~QID9#2~2~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student3phone = $('QR~QID9#2~3~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student4phone = $('QR~QID9#2~4~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student5phone = $('QR~QID9#2~5~1~TEXT').getValue();

    //Emails match
    var student1emailA = $('QR~QID9#3~1~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student1emailB = $('QR~QID9#4~1~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student2emailA = $('QR~QID9#3~2~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student2emailB = $('QR~QID9#4~2~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student3emailA = $('QR~QID9#3~3~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student3emailB = $('QR~QID9#4~3~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student4emailA = $('QR~QID9#3~4~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student4emailB = $('QR~QID9#4~4~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student5emailA = $('QR~QID9#3~5~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student6emailB = $('QR~QID9#4~5~1~TEXT').getValue();

    //Student book needs
    var student1booky = $('QR~QID9#5~1~1').getValue();
    var student1bookn = $('QR~QID9#5~1~2').getValue();
    var student2booky = $('QR~QID9#5~2~1').getValue();
    var student2bookn = $('QR~QID9#5~2~2').getValue();
    var student3booky = $('QR~QID9#5~3~1').getValue();
    var student3bookn = $('QR~QID9#5~3~2').getValue();
    var student4booky = $('QR~QID9#5~4~1').getValue();
    var student4bookn = $('QR~QID9#5~4~2').getValue();
    var student5booky = $('QR~QID9#5~5~1').getValue();
    var student6bookn = $('QR~QID9#5~5~2').getValue();

    //Student book name
    var student1bookname = $('QR~QID9#6~1~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student2bookname = $('QR~QID9#6~2~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student3bookname = $('QR~QID9#6~3~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student4bookname = $('QR~QID9#6~4~1~TEXT').getValue();
    var student5bookname = $('QR~QID9#6~5~1~TEXT').getValue();

    if (student1y == '') {
        //alert("no name provided, no other info needed");
        //"no name provided, no other info needed"

    } else if (student1y != '' && (student1phone == '' || (student1emailA == '' || student1emailB == '') || (student1booky == null && student1bookn == null))) {
        //alert("you need to provide a phone number and enter the student's book needs");
        notvalidphbook1 = 1;    
    } 

           else if (student1y != '' && (student1phone != '' && (student1emailA != '' && student1emailB != '') && (student1booky == null && student1bookn == null))) {

  notvalidphbook1 = 0;
             else {
        //alert("thank you for providing a phone number and specifying book needs");
        if (student1booky == 'QR~QID9#5~1~1') {
            bookrecode1 = 'Y';
        } else {
            bookrecode1 = 'N';
        }
    }

    if (student1emailA == '' && student1emailB == '') {
        //alert("no email provided, no match needed");
        //"no email provided, no match needed"

    } else if (student1emailA != '' && student1emailA == student1emailB) {
        //alert("the emails match");
        //"the emails match"
                    notvalidemail1 = 0;

    } else {
        //alert("the emails don't match");
        //"the emails don't match"
        notvalidemail1 = 1;
    }

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Student1Name', student1y);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Student1Phone', student1phone);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Student1Email', student1emailA);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Student1Txt', bookrecode1);
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Student1TxtName', student1bookname);

    phsbooks = notvalidphbook1 + notvalidphbook2 + notvalidphbook3 + notvalidphbook4 + notvalidphbook5;
    emails = notvalidemail1 + notvalidemail2 + notvalidemail3 + notvalidemail4 + notvalidemail5;

    validates = phsbooks + emails;

    if (validates == 0) { //validates only if the sum is equal to zero
        return true; //this let's the user continue
    } else {
        return false; //this prevents the user from proceeding to the next page
    }

}
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  here's a snapshot of what i am using: http://i.imgur.com/Y1AqcRU.jpg

Comment: so, what id like to do is 1) make columns 2-5 required, but only if column 1 (Name) is filled out.  that way a user can submit any number of student entries from 1-5 in the form, and responses for columns 2-5 are required for those they are submitting. 2) validate that the email address is an actual email address.  3) validate that the re-entered email address matches the first email address.  4) Make this question a Yes/No selection with re-coded entries to be 'Y' or 'N'.  The matrix table currently makes you select the same field type for all fields.

Comment: @655321, I'm trying to implement a similar logic as you suggested above, however, even though clearly the `validate` function on the question is executed every time I submit the page and validation fails with `return false`, it doesn't prevent me from moving on to the next page. Is there anything else to be combined with above to make this work?

Comment: skyork, are you using any type of validation (required or requested)? If you are, that interferes with this solution. It uses the same function and the Qualtrics validation (required or requested) takes precedence or overrides anything you put between:Qualtrics.SurveyPage.Question.prototype.validate = function (element) {. The best thing to do is not to use any type of validation from the question options and just do it fully customized in the questions javascript. I've learned the hard way.

Comment: @655321, That must be it (in my case, it's the required validation). I suspected it so while I was trying but now you've confirmed it. However, if I want to do everything in javascript, how do I block the user from moving on to the next question/page by making use of the value return by that `validate` function?

Comment: Yes, just return false based on the validation "violation". I had to dig into Qualtrics's JavaScript to figure it out. They're constantly rolling out new versions. I wish someone would add a "Qualtrics" tag to make it easier to find resources.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  So once I add the javascript for Students 2-5, the form could still be submitted with only row 1 filled out?  I thought selecting content validation and requiring response in Qualtrics for a column in a side-by-side means you have to complete that entire column, which is not what I want.

Comment: You don't need to fill out the rest. It will just do content validation only if you inputted any data for that field. Don't select require or request response, it will interfere with the JavaScript I wrote.

Comment: You don't need to fill out the rest. It will just do content validation only if you inputted any data for that field. Don't select require or request response, it will interfere with the JavaScript I wrote and would also nag you until you filled out all five students' information. The javascript as it is now will only require you to input a phone and textbook (y/n) if you have a name inputted (per your criteria).

Comment: Ah, sorry for any confusion, I probably stated it poorly by typing "2-5". Questions 2,3,4,5 need to be required. I need to both validate that the email address is a valid address, and validate that it matches the re-entered email address.

Comment: the current survey you posted compares the two emails, and stop the user from proceeding if they don't match...but then once they are corrected to match, you still can't proceed.  is that expected?

Comment: I updated the code and added this: notvalidemail1 = 0; It should work now. Sorry, I don't have a lot of time right now to finish up the rest. I will be back in a few days.

Comment: I updated the code and added this: notvalidemail1 = 0; It should work now. The rest should work as well.

Comment: thanks.  so it would be very similar to the first part, if you were going to add code to make both email address fields required?

Comment: Also, I don't see where the alerts like "Please enter a valid US phone number XXX-XXX-XXXX." are coming from.  how are those set up in your example?

Comment: did you ever get a chance to look at this again, 655321?  I'm having trouble getting this working; I'm not very experienced with Quartics.  When adding that javascript and un-commenting the 5 QID rows at the top, it didn't seem to have any effect on my question at all.  I must be missing something re: how to actually apply the javascript.

Comment: anyone able to help with how to apply the javascript in question?

Comment: It appears that Qualtrics has changed something; when I put in a simple version of the validation javascript that simply returns false, it doesn't prevent me from advancing. So it seems this mechanism is broken now. OP, or anyone else, any insight into how to make it work now??  Thanks!